# How to make fanout in Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to send message for all consumers, but before detect who should get this message, how to do that using Kafka?

Should I use Kafka stream to filter data then send to consumers?
As I know each consumers should be added to unique consumer group, but how to detect in real time, who must receive message ?

Comment: Can you give an clear example of what you're trying to do? It's not entirely clear.

Comment: I need to send message for all consumers

Comment: Each consumer subscribes to the topic, and receives all the messages.

Comment: How consumer can get mesaages if they was consumed by another conaumer from this topic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kafka decouples consumer and producer and when you write into a topic, you don't know which consumers might read the data.

Thus, in Kafka you never "send a message to a consumer", you just write the message into a topic and that's it.

Consumers just read from topics. Thus, you just need to spin up multiple consumers (with no consumer `group.id`, or different consumer `group.id` config) and each consumer will read all data, and thus you fan-out.

Comment: Hi, RabbitMQ decouples produces and consumers too, producers don't send messages to consumers either, they write to exchanges x)

Comment: Because from what I understand, the person asked something very different than what your response provided, it seemed like you were correcting him, while I believe his question was legit and required a different answer than the one you provided

Comment: Not sure if I can follow? The question does not mention RabbitMQ at all and explicitly asked about Kafka? -- What so you think the question is about? I understanding it as "how to a send a message to one or multiple specific consumers".

Comment: I had myself the question how to implement a "fanout" like feature on Kafka,  your response did not help, If you would have shared a piece of code of a minimal implementation it would have helped. I already know in Kafka we write to topics, yet I still had the question how people implement a "fanout" in Kafka.

Comment: I guess it depends what you exactly mean by "fanout". -- A producer could write a message to multiple topics/partitions or multiple consumers can read from the same topic/partition. -- Maybe start a new question about it.

Comment: I don't think the word "fanout" is ambiguous. At least for the ones who used rabbitmq before. It is a strategy that allows multiple consumers get the same message.

Comment: I am not familiar with RabbitMQ terminology. In Kafka, you have "fan out" by default (and can't even disable it): producers just write messages, and consumer just read from topic. Topic retain messages independent of consumers, and thus, as many consumers can read (and re-read) messages are long as they are retained by the brokers.

Comment: I am new to Kafka coming from the rabbitMq world as well. If you want a fanout, meaning all consumers receive the same message, each consumer would need to be in its own group. Since messages a dealt out to consumers by partition within a group. If you have 2 consumers within a group only 1 consumer will get that message.

Comment: This doesnt actually answer the question.

Comment: Why? If consumer "just read from topics", you can just spin up more consumers and they will read the data, and thus fan-out. (Added to the answer to be more explicit.)